# Link_to pointing to static route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a controller Pages and some actions for simple pages (contact us, for instance), then I went to `routes.rb` and created a route to allow users to go directly to /contactus, instead of /pages/contactus.

How can I point link_to to the action, but still getting the right route url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages, path: "", only: [] do #-> has to be above everything in routes file
  collection do
     get :contact_us #-> url.com/contact_us
     get :about      #-> url.com/about
  end
end

root ...
```

You'd link to it as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Contact", pages_contact_us_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get :contact_us, to: 'pages#contact_us'
```

or

```
get :contact_us, controller: :pages, action: :contact_us
```

this will generate path `contact_us_path` or url `contact_us_url`

[HEARE MORE ABOUT ROUTES IN RAILS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
get '/contactus', to: 'pages#contactus'
```

Your link can be:

```
<%= link_to "Contact Us", contactus_path %>
```

For more information, see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for a simple route using the `contactus` action in the `pages` controller:

`get '/contactus' => 'pages#contactus'`

or if you want a simpler name for your path:

`get '/contactus' => 'pages#contactus', as: :contact`